# where do files generated by an application running in wine go?

Tags: wine, fedora-13

I'm running FullTilt poker on my fedora 13 box over wine. I see that the hand history is stored here: `C:\Program Files\Full Tilt Poker\HandHistory`
but where does that mean they actually are on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been about two years since I last used Wine, if things have not changed... The `c:\` hard drive is enumerated from `~/.wine/drive_c` (where `~` is your home directory).

So, that directory should be... `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Full Tilt Poker/HandHistory`